# How to change the color and font size of my php?it is not working if i try

Tags: php, html, fonts, colors

I've been looking for ways to change the size and font of my php code output and can't find a way that doesn't cause errors. I want all of the following php code to appear white and enlarged:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['something'])) {
    echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['something'] .  ", <a href='something.php'>something</a>";
  }
?>
```

If anyone can help me with with achieving this that'd be great. So far I've tried font-color and color-span but neither have worked.

Comment: php has no colors/fonts. you're generating HTML, which DOES have that capability. set the appropriate `<font>` (eek, old/dead-school) or css

Comment: @MarcB note that recommending `<font>` is an absolutely insane idea: that tag hasn't been part of HTML since HTML4. So, since 1998 =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap your code into a span or div tag, and apply some CSS styling to it.

For example:

```
<?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['something'])){
            echo '<span style="color: white; font-size: 20px;">Welcome ' . $_SESSION['something'] .  ', <a href="something.php">something</a></span>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: Seems the best way. Would I define span style as #span in the css?

Comment: Just span, for styling all span tags. Otherwise, add an id to the span.

Comment: Just done what you said for the php code, and came up with the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'color' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in   "location:......"

Comment: Did you add the styling outside your php tags?

Comment: No thats just applying the code you gave me above, do I need style in css to get rid of errors then?

Comment: Try again please, code above is updated ;)

Comment: Thanks alot, its working now :)